# How to fetch data from EMR Spark session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, metadata, airflow, amazon-emr

I'm doing designing some ETL data pipelines with Airflow. Data transformations is done by provisioning an AWS EMR Spark cluster and sending its some jobs. The jobs read data from S3, process them and write them back to S3 using date as a partition.

For my last step, I need to load the S3 data to a datawarehouse using SQL scripts that are submitted to Redshift using Python script, however I cannot find a clean way to get retrieve which data need to be loaded, ie. which date partitions have been generated during Spark transformations (can only be known during the execution of the job and not beforehand).

Note that everything is orchestrated through a Python script using boto3 library that is run from a corporate VM that cannot be accessed from outside.

What would be the best way to fetch this information from EMR?

For now I'm thinking about different solutions:
- Write the information into a log file. Get the data from Spark master node using SSH through Python script
- Write the information to an S3 file
- Write the information to a database (RDS?)

I'm struggling to determine what are the pros and the cons of these solutions. I'm also wondering what would be the best way to inform that data transformations is over and that metadata can be fetched.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward is to use S3 as your temporary storage. After finishing your Spark execution (Writing result to S3), you can add one more step writing data to S3 bucket which you want to get in next step.

The approach with RDS should be the similar to S3, but it requires more implementations than S3. You need to setup RDS, maintain Schema, implementation to work with RDS...

With S3 tmp file, after EMR terminated and AF running next step, using Boto to fetch that tmp file (S3 Path depends on your requirement) and that is it.